# Angular2 rxjs/Subject I dont get notification

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to get notification on parent component from child components, after loading them, using injected service.

I am using routing in order to navigate to child component, and using the 'router-outlet' I just don't get the notification (without routing and using a selector it is working).

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kPq8Iq5R1msafz0ORw4A?p=preview)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { PageHeader }   from './page-header.model';

@Injectable()
export class PageHeaderService{
    private headerTitleSource = new Subject<PageHeader>();
    headerTitle$ = this.headerTitleSource.asObservable();

    setTitle(header:PageHeader) {
        this.headerTitleSource.next(header);
    }
}
```

What am I missing or don't understand in the structure?

Comment: The Plunker throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{header?.title}}`

Your code is fine.
The header setting is asynchronous and the view was loading early.
Your console had undefined error. The question mark in `app.component.ts`  solved it.